# Symfony dependency-injection component. Autowiring not working

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm currently working on creating a framework based on Symfony components for my own curiosity.

I want to use the symfony/dependency-injection component and its autowiring system.

The routing (with annotations) is working correctly but when i try to autowire a service (internal or external), I get the error :

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Shopper\Controller\IndexController::__construct(), 0 passed in
```

I created a repository to help you answering my question : https://github.com/kerwanp/shopper

Comment: The default ControllerResolver is not container aware so it will always use new IndexController.  Use the ContainerControllerResolver instead.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer ! In "framework" arguments i have to change "controller_resolver" from `HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver::class` to `HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver::class` ? It's not working, i'm misunderstanding something i think

Comment: You will of course have to inject the container into the resolver and ensure that your controllers are being defined as public services.  I don't have an example handy.  But you could perhaps break on ContainerControllerResolver::instantiateController to see what is going on.

Comment: Do you mean "Inject the resolver into the container" no ? My controller is defined as a service (https://gist.github.com/kerwanp/5ad109080d472b0ab998797022b5dc82)
The ContainerControllerResolver extends ControllerResolver and instantiate the controller only with : `return new $class();` Which does not pass any argument.

Comment: A few points: You should include the relevant code (and only the relevant code) **within your question**, not as an external link. Also, the linked code does not seem to be the code that's raising this error (there is no `IndexController` in that example). Also, for some reason you are including the `autoloader.php` script twice, don't do that.

Comment: No.  I mean inject the container into the resolver as a dependency.  If you are not doing this then you would get a missing argument error for your resolver.  Look at ContainerControllerResolver::instantiateController and you will see where it tests to see if the container has the desired controller defined as a service and returns it.  Might want to update your gist with your latest code.  Better yet, consider making a git repo with a complete almost working example.  I'd be happy to clone it and debug it.

Comment: @Cerad i'm a bit confused, i think that an example could help me a lot, i really do not know where I can pass the container into the resolver. And i do not find something similar in the Symfony project.
The repository of the project : https://github.com/kerwanp/shopper (post also edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. Needed a few tweaks.

First and most important, you need to compile the container before using it:

```
# index.php
$container = $containerLoader->getContainerBuilder();
$container->compile(); ### ADD THIS ###
```

Once you add the compile you will get various container related error messages that need fixing.

Autowire tries to wire your AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader and fails because of a needed dependency.  So you need to ignore it:

```
# services.yaml ADD The Annotation directory
  Shopper\:
    resource: '../*'
    exclude: '../{Annotation,DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

After that you need to tweak the ContainerControllerResolver to inject the container.  Note that the 'service_container' service is sort of a built in service that resolves to the container:

```
# ContainerLoader
        $this->containerBuilder->register('controller_resolver', HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver::class)
            ->setArguments([new Reference('service_container')]);
```

Finally, services that are registered via code are private by default.  You need to explicitly set your 'framework' service as public:

```
# ContainerLoader
        $this->containerBuilder->register('framework', Kernel::class)
            ->setArguments([
                new Reference('dispatcher'),
                new Reference('controller_resolver'),
                new Reference('request_stack'),
                new Reference('argument_resolver'),
            ])
            ->setPublic(true) ### ADD THIS ###
        ;
```

And that should do it.  I should point out that using service names like 'request_stack' is a bit old school.  In most cases, you should consider using class names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this perfectly written answer !

Comment: Glad to help.  Once you get a bit further be sure to research how to cache the container and your routes.  Completely rebuilding the container on each request is going to be a bit slow.